# validates() method in model usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

Just a quick question on the validates() method. When you're using it in the model, is there a way to write them to use the least amount of lines as possible?

Example say this is my model

```
class Items < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :price, presence: true
end
```

And say I want to add numericality to price and uniquness to title.

is there a way to write that on one line instead of doing

```
validate :title, uniqueness: true
validate :price, numericality: {greater_or_equal_to: 0.01}
```

Hopefully the question makes sense.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that, but even if you could you shouldn't. It would make it notably less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can organize multiple attributes on one line that share the same validations

```
validates :foo, :bar, presence: true
validates :x, :y, numericality: { allow_blank: true }
```

This works really well for me. It's not unusual in my work to deal with tables with 20+ columns, reviewing all of those on one line of code would be a nightmare. You could write a custom validation method to try and put things on one line, but I don't think that's worth the effort. IE

```
validate :custom_method
```

Followed by:

```
def custom_method
errors.add(:foo, 'must have value') if self.foo.nil? ; errors.add(:bar, 'must have value') if self.bar.nil?
end
```

I hope that illustrates why accepting the extra line may be ok in the long run.

**edit**

Rails doesn't seem to complain if you were to do something like:

```
  validates :foo, length: { maximum: 12 }, presence: true ; validates :bar, length: { maximum: 40 }
```

Comment: Ah that's a much better approach (the multiple attirbutes that share the same validation). Thanks for that!